# Run command recursively through subdirectories

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to convert a bunch of images to thumbnails that might be in several subdirectories, and save a copy of the image as a thumbnail inside the subdirectory, but I can't figure out the syntax. Any advice would be welcome.

```
convert test/*/*.jpg -50x50 test/*/*_thumb.jpg
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use find for finding all files you need.

```
find test -iname *.jpg -exec convert {} -resize 50x50 {}_thumb \;
```

And then you should rename files with name *.jpg_thumb to *_thumb.jpg by using:

```
find -name *.jpg_thumb -exec rename -e 's/^(.*)(.jpg)(_thumb)$/\1\3\2/' '{}' \;
```

Note that -50x50 is not a legal parameter for convert. You should use `-resize` parameter with value `50x50` like in example above.

Answer (score 6):

A shell loop should also do:

```
for file in test/*/*.jpg ; do
    new=${file%.jpg}_thumb.jpg 
    convert "$file" -resize 50x50 "$new"
done
```

Or with Bash's `globstar`, which is better if the files can be on arbitrary directory levels:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in test/**/*.jpg ; do ...
```

`${file%.jpg}` takes the value of the variable `file` and removes the string `.jpg` from the end. (see [BashGuide on parameter expansions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion))